# Why does Metricbeat is running but do not provide any metrics?

Tags: docker, elastic-stack, docker-swarm, elk, metricbeat

Hellow everyone,

I have an Elastic Stack running in a swarm of docker: ELK 7.7.0 + Filebeat + Metricbeat.
After an Metricbeat service restart (maybe not and I missed something) it stopped to provide metrics.

The service did provide metrics few days ago. No config changes were made to ES, Kibana and Metricbeat config on this few days.
ES and KIbana is running fine and, for example, Filebeat shows some metrics.
`docker server logs elk-cluster_metricbeat` - shows nothing at all.
`docker stack services elk-cluster` - shows that all replicas of the service is running.

Where I need to look to find a malfunction?

UPD: Indices does not been created